# SearchView is not working in my application i want to search the values from the database

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with search view. I want to use search view in my application. In my application I am adding user details, and I want to search the user details using search view.

Here I am posting the code please help me out.

my activity where I am requesting the

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_search:
               Log.i("sample", "cliked");
            onSearchRequested();
                break;
```

and serchview activity is as look like below I am using sqlite in the below code.
The problem is it is not calling the searchviewactivity.

```
    private ListView mListView;
        private SearchView searchView;
        private CustomersDbAdapter mDbHelper;
        Cursor cursor;
        private TextView inspectionDate;
        private TextView customerText;
        private TextView nameText;
        private TextView addressText;
        private TextView cityText;
        private TextView stateText;
        private TextView zipCodeText;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            inspectionDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inspectionDate);
            displayDate();
            mDbHelper = new CustomersDbAdapter(this);
            try {
                mDbHelper.open();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          //Clean all Customers
            mDbHelper.deleteAllCustomers();
            //Add some Customer data as a sample
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA1", "Pizza Hut", "1107 West Adams Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA2", "Pizza Hut", "1562 West Pico Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA3", "Pizza Hut", "718 South Los Angeles Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90014");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA4", "Pizza Hut", "2542 West Temple Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90026");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA5", "Pizza Hut", "4329 North Figueroa Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90065");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("PIZZA6", "Pizza Hut", "4351 South Central Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90011");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("SUB1", "Subway", "975 West Jefferson", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("SUB2", "Subway", "2805 South Figueroa Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("SUB3", "Subway", "198 South Vermont Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90004");
            mDbHelper.createCustomer("SUB4", "Subway", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mDbHelper  != null) {
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            showResults(newText + "*");
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            showResults(query + "*");
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onClose() {
            showResults("");
            return false;
        }
        private void showResults(String query) {


            try {
                cursor = mDbHelper.searchCustomer((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (cursor == null) {
                //
            } else {
                // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
                String[] from = new String[] {
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_CUSTOMER,
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS,
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_CITY,
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_STATE,
                        CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_ZIP};   

                // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
                int[] to = new int[] {     R.id.scustomer,
                        R.id.sname,
                        R.id.saddress,
                        R.id.scity,
                        R.id.sstate,
                        R.id.szipCode};

                // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView

                SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.customerresult, cursor, from, to);
                mListView.setAdapter(customers);

                // Define the on-click listener for the list items
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Log.i("Cursor", cursor+"");
                        // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                        String customer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("customer"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", cursor+"");
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", customer+"");
                        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", address+"");
                        String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("city"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", city+"");
                        String state = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("state"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", state+"");
                        String zipCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("zipCode"));
                        Log.i("Cursor", zipCode+"");
                        Toast.makeText(SearchViewActivity.this, ""+customer+""+name+""+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Check if the Layout already exists
                        LinearLayout customerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.customerLayout);
                        if(customerLayout == null){
                            //Inflate the Customer Information View 
                            LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
                            View customerInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customerinfo, leftLayout, false);
                            leftLayout.addView(customerInfo);


                        //Get References to the TextViews
                        customerText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.customer);
                        nameText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.name);
                        addressText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.address);
                        cityText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.city);
                        stateText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.state);
                        zipCodeText = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.zipCode);


                        // Update the parent class's TextView
                        customerText.setText(customer);
                        nameText.setText(name);
                        addressText.setText(address);
                        cityText.setText(city);
                        stateText.setText(state);
                        zipCodeText.setText(zipCode);
                        }
                        searchView.setQuery("",true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private void displayDate() {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            inspectionDate.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("/")
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("/")
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
        }
    }
```

Here I am posting the manifest details which is in the customer details activity. I need to call the search view. I am calling it but its not working. I am struck with the code please help me out.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

               <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxx.customerdetails.CustomerDetalsActivity" >
                     <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                        android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                        android:value=".SearchViewActivity" />

        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".SearchViewActivity" >            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                         android:launchMode="singleTop" />

            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>            
        </activity>
```

Comment: why are you appedning `*` to`newText `

Comment: rajan i used * to retrive all the fields from the sqlite

Answer (score 0):

This should be your query to retrieve all data matches the name with that string

```
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           String query ="SELECT * FROM "+TABLENAME+" WHERE "+KEYNAME+" like '%"+newText+"%'"
           showResults(query);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: i am able to display the search bar to enter the values but i it is not going to display or the control is not going to searchViewActivity  please help out